# Issue while Combining multiple rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

1. I want to build the query according to the following conditions,
2. I just want to combine the sum the Total price of both type 1 and type 2.
3. Combine 2 rows into 1 and avoid null values in that rows.

Query,

```
select B.ID as BillId, 
       I.Id as ItemID, 
       t.Type, 
       SUM(I.TotalPrice) as TotalPrice, 
       Case when t.Type = 1 then SUM(T.Amount) end as TaxAmountType1,
       Case when t.Type = 2 then SUM(T.Amount) end as TaxAmountType2 
  from Bill B
       inner join ItemDetails I 
           on I.BillNoID = B.ID
       inner join TaxDetails T 
           on T.ItemDetailId = I.Id
group by 
       B.ID, 
       I.Id, 
       I.TotalPrice, 
       t.Type;
```

Please refer below image,
[image]

[image]
Expected Output:

'1', '1', NULL, '40.00', '3.00', '5.00'

Note:
1. I dont want to use sub-query.
2. Expected output "NULL" refers i don't want to show that column seperately.

Comment: If your query would be text instead of an image we would not have to write that one all new.

Comment: I have updated. Please take a look.

Comment: @juergen d did you able to find the solution ?

Comment: @juergen d Code was into 3 level. 1. TotalTax according to type. 2. Total Amount account to ItemDetail table. 3. Final result generate according to bill table.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this would solve your problem. If not please give more informations.

```
SELECT B.ID as BillId, I.Id as ItemId, 
       t.type, SUM(TotalPrice), SUM(TaxAmountType1), 
       SUM(TaxAmountType2) 
FROM Bill B 
GROUP BY BillId, ItemId, t.type
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't group by the column that you're trying to aggregate. Remove the I.TotalPrice from the GROUP BY:

```
select B.ID as BillId, I.Id as ItemID, t.Type, SUM(I.TotalPrice) as TotalPrice, 
    Case when t.Type = 1 then SUM(T.Amount) end as TaxAmountType1,
    Case when t.Type = 2 then SUM(T.Amount) end as TaxAmountType2 from Bill B
inner join ItemDetails I on I.BillNoID = B.ID
inner join TaxDetails T on T.ItemDetailId = I.Id
group by B.ID, I.Id, t.Type;`
```

Comment: Code was into 3 level. 1. TotalTax according to type. 2. Total Amount account to ItemDetail table. 3. Final result generate according to bill table.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select B.ID as BillId, I.Id as ItemID, null as Type, SUM(I.TotalPrice) as TotalPrice, 
Case when t.Type = 1 then SUM(T.Amount) end as TaxAmountType1,
Case when t.Type = 2 then SUM(T.Amount) end as TaxAmountType2
from Bill B
inner join ItemDetails I on I.BillNoID = B.ID
inner join TaxDetails T on T.ItemDetailId = I.Id
group by B.ID, I.Id, I.TotalPrice
```

You don't want to group by type, that's the issue (you also can remove the ", null as Type" from the select)

Comment: I just want to group by type, because i want to seperate the tax amount by type 1  and type 2.

Comment: If any other idea pls let me know.

Comment: If you expect to get '1', '1', NULL, '40.00', '3.00', '5.00' you are not grouping by type. Please put your exact output expected with columns header

Answer (score 0):

If you group by t.type, you wont be able to have those instances in the same line.
Try:

```
select B.ID as BillId, I.Id as ItemID, t.Type, SUM(I.TotalPrice) as TotalPrice, 
Case when t.Type = 1 then SUM(T.Amount) end as TaxAmountType1,
Case when t.Type = 2 then SUM(T.Amount) end as TaxAmountType2 from Bill B
inner join ItemDetails I on I.BillNoID = B.ID
inner join TaxDetails T on T.ItemDetailId = I.Id
group by B.ID, I.Id, I.TotalPrice;
```